# BigQuery "Response Too Large To Return" when trying to ORDER BY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that finds all the events that a user's "last" day (ie, does not show up again for 2+ weeks). I want to whittle this down to the last N events they perform before leaving in order of most recent to least recent.

I created an unordered table without issue, but when I try to **ORDER BY timestamp DESC**, it then gives me a "Response too large to return" error.
Why do I get this error when trying to sort (no GROUP BYs or anything), but not on the unordered table?

*EDITED TO ADD QUERY BELOW*

This query gives me the table with events for users who have not shown up in the last 14 days.

```
SELECT user.user_key as user_key, user.lastTime as lastTime, evt.actiontime as actiontime, evt.actiontype as actiontype, evt.action_parameters.parameter_name as actionParameterName
FROM (
  SELECT user_key , MAX(actiontime) AS lastTime, DATE(MAX(actiontime)) as lastDate
  FROM [db.action_log]
  WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), actiontime) >= 14
  GROUP EACH BY user_key
  HAVING DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), lastTime) >= 14) as user
JOIN EACH(
  SELECT user_key, actiontime, actiontype, action_parameters.parameter_name, DATE(actiontime) as actionDate
  FROM [db.action_log]
  WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), actiontime) >= 14) as evt
ON (user.user_key = evt.user_key) AND (user.lastDate = evt.actionDate)
WHERE actiontime <= lastTime;
```

And this runs just fine. I want to GROUP_CONCAT() to turn the actions into a list, but first I need to sort by actiontime (descending) so that the most recent event is the first in the list. But when I run:

```
SELECT user_key, lastTime, actiontime, user_level, actiontype, actionParameterName
FROM [db.lastActions]
ORDER BY actiontime DESC;
```

I get "Response too large to return."

Comment: Please include a query if possible, more people will be able to help. Or a job id if it looks like a bug that the team should debug, but prefer the community approach while on StackOverflow.

Comment: Good point, should have included those initially. Queries edited in to initial post.

Comment: Sort as an operation is not distributed, so it's limited to all the data that will fit in one node. To test this, can you check if the same query runs when filtering out a chunk of the original data?

Comment: I tried to filter using HASH. If I do WHERE HASH(user_key) % 100 = 0, this works fine. If I do HASH(user_key) % 100 < 1, it returns "Resources exceeded during this operation". 
Anyway, that's another issue. Filtering on another field, I managed to get it to sort 4.2M rows (~ 1/3 of total) before hitting "Resources exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

BQ sometimes shouts at you when you have too many combinations of `group, order and group_concats` in a single query.
However, I believe that a straight `group_concat` does **not** create an ordered list, so doing an `order by` before the concat is essentially meaningless in this case.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by) should solve your problem though

For completions sake, I have found several useful ways to get around getting shouted at (for whatever reason):
1)  Break up your script into smaller segments if possible.  This way you can have more control if you are playing around with data.
2)  Instead of using `order by` and then `limit`, it will be quicker and may be more useful to use more where statements.
3)  Use subselects - wisely.  For example grouping first and then ordering should always be quicker than ordering first for example.