# BigQuery GROUP_CONCAT and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently using BigQuery and GROUP_CONCAT which works perfectly fine. However, when I try to add a ORDER BY clause to the GROUP_CONCAT statement like I would do in SQL, I receive an error.

So e.g., something like

`SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(b ORDER BY c)
FROM test
GROUP BY a`

The same happens if I try to specify the separator.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Similar to SQLite, BigQuery does not support `order by` in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since BigQuery doesn't support ORDER BY clause inside GROUP_CONCAT function, this functionality can be achieved by use of analytic window functions. And in BigQuery separator for GROUP_CONCAT is simply a second parameter for the function.
Below example illustrates this:

```
select key, first(grouped_value) concat_value from (
select 
  key, 
  group_concat(value, ':') over 
    (partition by key
     order by value asc
     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
  grouped_value 
from (
select key, value from
(select 1 as key, 'b' as value),
(select 1 as key, 'c' as value),
(select 1 as key, 'a' as value),
(select 2 as key, 'y' as value),
(select 2 as key, 'x' as value))) group by key
```

Will produce the following:

```
Row key concat_value     
1   1   a:b:c    
2   2   x:y
```

NOTE on Window specification: The query uses "rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following" window specification, to make sure that all rows within a partition participate in GROUP_CONCAT aggregation. Per SQL Standard default window specification is "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" which is good for things like running sum, but won't work correctly in this problem.

Performance note: Even though it looks wasteful to recompute aggregation function multiple times, the BigQuery optimizer does recognize that since window is not changing result will be the same, so it only computes aggregation once per partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what ```rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following``` does? It seems to speed up the query heavily.

Comment: I augmented the answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, I receive  "Error: Resources exceeded during query execution." for this query on a huge dataset. Any idea how to approach this? I can also open a new question.

Comment: Possibly use GROUP EACH BY instead of GROUP BY ?

Comment: Another quick question: How can I ignore subsequent duplicates. So e.g., instead of "a:b:b:c" I would like to have "a:b:c".

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky very neat.  My question is what its peer in Standard SQL should be?  because STRING_AGG() doesn't work with OVER()

Comment: I added another answer - in Standard SQL you can just use ORDER BY inside STRING_AGG

Answer (score 17):

Standard SQL mode in BigQuery does support ORDER BY clause within some aggregate functions, including STRING_AGG, for example:

```
#standardSQL
select string_agg(t.x order by t.y) 
from unnest([struct<x STRING, y INT64>('a', 5), ('b', 1), ('c', 10)]) t
```

will result in

`b,a,c`

Documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#using-order-by-with-aggregate-functions

Comment: This is clearer and helpful answer, especially for case where table contains multiple REPEATED columns which have to be `group_concat`-ed separately. `select some_column, (select string_agg(val order by val) from unnest(repeated_column1)) as r1, (select string_agg(val2 order by val2) from unnest(repeated_column2)) as r2 from tbl` is the way. Window-function-based solution would be complicated in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version in Standard SQL mode in BigQuery with ARRAY_AGG as aggregate function:

```
select key,
array_agg(struct(grouped_value) order by array_length(grouped_value) desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from (
select 
  key, 
  array_agg(value) over 
    (partition by key
     order by value asc
     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
  grouped_value 
from (
select key, value from unnest([
    struct(1 as key, "b" as value)
  , struct(1, "c")
  , struct(1, "a")
  , struct(2, "y")
  , struct(2, "x")
]))) group by key
```