# Resources exceeded error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently running the following query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT a, FIRST(grouped_value) concat_value
FROM (SELECT a, group_concat(subreddit) over
(partition by a order by order_field asc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
grouped_value
from
[long_list_of_tables] )
GROUP EACH BY a
```

Unfortunately, I end up with the following error:

```
Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.
Job ID: trusty-spanner-100412:job_cKtzW1aYFUSuRjixSiShghOAe-s
```

My limit is not reached as I can run other queries fine.

Comment: can you post the full query? easier to debug and advice

Answer (score 1):

The query here is from the answer to "[GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by)"

I checked your query, and the results of GROUP_CONCAT are growing too big. So I think maybe there is another approach to use. BigQuery will soon announce general availability of Javascript UDFs, and then sorting and removing duplicates inside a string becomes simple Javascript code. Once the feature becomes public, I will make sure to publish example which does sorting and removing duplicates using Javascript.

Comment: It is too bad that all the queries I need at the moment run into the "Resources exceeded during query execution" error.

Answer (score 0):

This error message has nothing to do with quota, but with how the system shards your queries to try and run it.

Do you really need the EACH in your group by? 
Normally you put each only if you know a will have a lot of distinct values, at the cost of more processing.

Also, when you run this query, do you "[allow large results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults)?"  If not, then it's possible that you're running into that error

Comment: I suspect something is going with BQ lately, as in the last couple of days we seen a performance drop, see my reported Performance issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=283&sort=-id

Comment: Yes, I am already allowing large results. If I just use ```GROUP BY``` instead of ```GROUP EACH BY``` I receive: ```Error: Resources exceeded during query execution. The query contained a GROUP BY operator, consider using GROUP EACH BY instead.```

Comment: Ok, then your keys have enough entropy that it shouldn't be a problem. Did the query ever run?

Comment: @Pentium10 - the performance issue you reported is somewhat narrow focused, and is realted to queries with large number of joins. It doesn't affect "Resources exceeded" or general performance of BigQuery.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky The same queries did run fine a couple of weeks ago. Max 2-3 minutes. I am open to suggestions, you have my email.