# Bigquery - How to cast float to string w/o round up/down?

Tags: google-bigquery

Basically I have a batch of GPS coordinates(lat and long), I wanted to have a string formatted as "lat;long". What I did was:

```
CONCAT(CAST(Latitude AS STRING),";", CAST(Longitude AS STRING))
```

But ran into a problem where the coordinates were rounded up by CAST (STRING() did the same thing). for example, by `select CAST(45.3618927 as STRING)` I'll get 45.3619.  How can I prevent this rounding?

Note:  I know SAFE_CAST in the standard SQL gives me what I want, but for other reasons I'd have to stay with Legacy dialect.

Comment: That exactly example works perfectly in Standard SQL! no any rounding. What exactly keeps you with Legacy SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT CONCAT(
  RTRIM(CONCAT(LEFT(lat_temp, lat_pos - 1), '.', SUBSTR(lat_temp, lat_pos)), '0'), 
  ';',
  RTRIM(CONCAT(LEFT(lon_temp, lon_pos - 1), '.', SUBSTR(lon_temp, lon_pos)), '0') 
  ) AS lat_lon
FROM (
  SELECT 
    INSTR(STRING(lat * 1000000), '.') - 6 AS lat_pos, 
    REPLACE(STRING(lat * 1000000),'.', '') AS lat_temp,
    INSTR(STRING(lon * 1000000), '.') - 6 AS lon_pos, 
    REPLACE(STRING(lon * 1000000),'.', '') AS lon_temp
  FROM 
    (SELECT 34.052235 AS lat, -118.243683 AS lon) AS yourTable
)
```

Sure looks ugly, but as you said  - for some reason you want to stick wirg Legacy SQL
Otherwise see below for Standard SQL version

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 34.052235 AS lat, -118.243683 AS lon
)
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(lat AS STRING),";", CAST(lon AS STRING)) AS lat_lon
FROM yourTable
```

Another (less ugly) version for Legacy SQL is with using of [JS UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)

```sql
#legacySQL 
SELECT lat, lon, lat_lon
FROM (JS(
  -- input table
  (
    SELECT lat, lon FROM
    (SELECT 34.052235 AS lat, -118.243683 AS lon) AS yourTable
  ),
  -- input vars
  lat, lon, 
  -- output schema
  "[
    {name: 'lat_lon', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'lat', type: 'FLOAT'},
    {name: 'lon', type: 'FLOAT'}
    ]",
  -- the function
  "function(row, emit) {
    emit({
      lat_lon: row.lat.toString().concat(';').concat(row.lon.toString()),
      lat: row.lat,
      lon: row.lon
    })
  }"
))
```

And, finally, if by chance - you will decide to migrate to [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql), use of [FORMAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string-format) makes life much more easier (thanks to Elliott for commenting on this)

```sql
#standardSQL 
SELECT FORMAT('%t;%t', lat, lon) AS lat_lon 
FROM
  (SELECT 34.052235 AS lat, -118.243683 AS lon) AS yourTable
```

Comment: Another option that doesn't require `CAST` at all is to use `FORMAT`. For example, `SELECT FORMAT('%t;%t', lat, lon) AS lat_lon FROM yourTable;`

Comment: OP wanted legacy SQL version. I purposely used his own example as alternative for Standard SQL. If to really go with Standard SQL - using `FORMAT` is much more sexier :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant   @.@ reading the answers, I feel almost I'd want to try way harder to move to standard dialect...   The reason of sticking with legacy was that I didn't know STRING_AGG() does work with ORDER BY. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by  where Mosha Pasumansky provided the answer. I'll go now and have a try on these for my case. Thanks all!