# SQL distinct values per group - how to "group by" and get a list of distinct values per group?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, distinct

I need to do a bigquery/standard SQL statement  (or a series of statements) that does "group by", and returns a list of distinct values for each group (not count).

for example for tables with headers H1,H2

```
H1 H2  
--|--
a  a   
a  b
a  c
b  x
b  x
b  y
```

the expected result from "group by" H1:

```
a->a,b,c
b->x,y
```

Comment: You can take help from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'r using `array_agg` dont forget to use DISTINCT

```
select h1, array_agg(DISTINCT h2)
from t
group by h1;
```

Comment: keep in mind that if your using MySql there is no array_agg function.
but you can use group_concat instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STRING_AGG()` - find **[reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions)** here

```
SELECT H1, STRING_AGG(H2) AS H2 
FROM tablename
group by H1
```

Comment: for future reference ,in  mysql its GROUP_CONCAT and in psotgres and bigquery STRING_AGG

Comment: This legit works for Google Big Query. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use `array_agg()`:

```
select h1, array_agg(h2)
from t
group by h1;
```

If you are using BigQuery, learn to use arrays.  They are very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Use BigQuery Arrays.

```
select 
   h1, 
   array_agg(distinct h2) as items
from `dataset.table`
group by h1
```

If you want the above distinct grouping to be flattened again:

```
select h1, item from (
   select 
      h1, 
      array_agg(distinct h2) as items
   from `dataset.table`
   group by h1
), unnest(items) as item
```