# Having difficulty generating distinct rows without duplicates in a SELF JOIN (SQL)

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, self-join

I'm pretty new to SQL and thought I'd be able to use it to create a list for my employer's clients. Unfortunately, there the majority of clients have more than one account and the file has a distinct row for each account.

I was trying to use a self join to create one row for each client with multiple columns for the accounts.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Account_Number AS Account_1, B.Account_Number AS Account_2, A.Client_Name
FROM client_table AS A, client_table AS B
WHERE A.Account_Number <> B.Account_Number
AND A.Client_Name = B.Client_Name
ORDER BY A.Client_Name;
```

Unfortunately, the results were such that I would get a table that looks like:

| Account_1 | Account_2 | Client_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 000002 | Joe Shmo |
| 000001 | 000003 | Joe Shmo |
| 000002 | 000003 | Joe Shmo |
| 000002 | 000001 | Joe Shmo |

I understand that for more than two accounts, I'll need more than two joins, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Is there a way to prevent double entry?

I'm using BigQuery btw.

Comment: In addition to that, I've tried to use ```WHERE A.Account_Number < B.Account_Number ```, and it works for individuals with only two accounts, but 'duplicates' are created when there are three or more.

Comment: What is the output you want here?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your request with it. And you do know that you are using a deprecated join syntax that as made redundant about 30 years ago? Please use explicit joins as introduced in standard SQL 1992 (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, ...).

Comment: As a SQL query results in a table with a fixed number of columns, how many account columns do you want to select? What if a client has more than these? (Such layout tasks are usually better handled outside the DBMS in your app or Website.)

Comment: The clients have anywhere from 2 to 6 accounts with us. We have 500+ clients and figured SQL would be faster than excel.

Comment: Is my suggestion with GROUP_CONCAT good for you? If you are sure that there are never more than 6 accounts there is another method that we could use.

Comment: I cant seem to get the GROUP_CONCAT to work in BigQuery. I'm getting the Function not found error message.

Comment: The aggregation string concatenation function in Google BigQuery is `STRING_AGG`, not `GROUP_CONCAT`. Docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step number the accounts per client. Then use conditional aggregation to get one column per account.

```
select 
  client_name,
  max(case when rn = 1 then account_number end) as account1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then account_number end) as account2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then account_number end) as account3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then account_number end) as account4,
  max(case when rn = 5 then account_number end) as account5,
  max(case when rn = 6 then account_number end) as account6
from
(
  select
    client_name,
    account_number,
    row_number() over (partition by client_name order by account_number) as rn
  from client_table
) numbered
group by client_name
order by client_name;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much Thorsten. I really appreciate the help. I found that each account had a sub account that basically just created additional entries of the same account. So I cleaned that with a quick remove duplicates function in Sheets and reloaded the data to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `LEFT JOIN`. Repeat as necessary for however many accounts a user may have.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct.Client_Name, ct1.Account_Number AS Account_1, ct2.Account_Number AS Account_2,
                ct3.Account_Number AS Account_3, ct4.Account_Number AS Account_4
FROM client_table ct
LEFT JOIN client_table ct1 ON ct1.Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND ct1.Account_Number = (SELECT MIN(Account_Number) FROM client_table WHERE Client_Name = ct.Client_Name)
LEFT JOIN client_table ct2 ON ct2.Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND ct2.Account_Number = (SELECT MIN(Account_Number) FROM client_table WHERE Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND Account_Number > ct1.Account_Number)
LEFT JOIN client_table ct3 ON ct3.Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND ct3.Account_Number = (SELECT MIN(Account_Number) FROM client_table WHERE Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND Account_Number > ct2.Account_Number)
LEFT JOIN client_table ct4 ON ct4.Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND ct4.Account_Number = (SELECT MIN(Account_Number) FROM client_table WHERE Client_Name = ct.Client_Name AND Account_Number > ct3.Account_Number)
```

Comment: I should have included that I'm currently working with BigQuery, which doesn't seem to recognize OUTER APPLY. I genuinely appreciate the insight though.

Comment: @Tyler You can convert `OUTER APPLY` into a `LEFT JOIN` the syntax is just arguably cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to fetch a comma seperated list.
Or you can use `RANK()`to order your accounts in a `CTE`and then list them.
Attention : any 7th accounts or above will not be shown!

> ```
> create table clients (
> cname varchar(10),
> account char(6));
> insert into clients values
> ('Joe Shmo','000001'),
> ('Joe Shmo','000002'),
> ('Joe Shmo','000003'),
> ('Joe Shmo','000004');
> ```

> ```
> select 
>    cname "Name", 
>    group_concat(account ) account_numbers
> from clients
> group by cname
> order by cname;
> ```

> ```
> Name     | account_numbers            
> :------- | :--------------------------
> Joe Shmo | 000001,000002,000003,000004
> ```

> ```
> with c as 
> (select
> cname,
> account,
> rank() over (partition by cname order by account) ranking
> from clients)
> select 
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=1 then account end),'   -') account1,
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=2 then account end),'   -') account2,
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=3 then account end),'   -') account3,
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=4 then account end),'   -') account4,
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=5 then account end),'   -') account5,
> coalesce(max(case when ranking=6 then account end),'   -') account6
> from c
> group by cname
> ```

> ```
> account1 | account2 | account3 | account4 | account5 | account6
> :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-------
> 000001   | 000002   | 000003   | 000004   |    -     |    -
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=dfd991c76a3e878a4335d22d8fbaae18)*

Please see the following post for more information on group_concat in bigQuery: [BigQuery GROUP_CONCAT and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368235/bigquery-group-concat-and-order-by)